# Get content from a list Android

Tags: android, list, get

how can I get the content from a list e.g.

```
Product[] items = {
            new Product("test1",07,07,2013),
            new Product("test2",07,07,2013),
            new Product("test3",07,07,2013),
    };
```

and put this in a onItemClick().
if someone click the first line it should output test1 7.7.2013.
And this line isn't the same as my listview.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onItemClick` callback do `mMyAdapter.getItem(position)`

Comment: It doesn't work because listview content isn't the same as this list.

Comment: well then just use the position variable provided by the onItemClick and use it as a index of array, easy java stuff

Comment: have your "items" be a field variable and the in the onItemClick method do Product product = items[position];